# Type is not as polymorphic as suggested

Tags: frege

I'd like to build an abstraction to use different template engines:

```
class Template a where
  process :: a -> Model -> IO String

class TemplateEngine a where
  buildTemplate :: (Template b) => a -> BufferedReader -> IO b
```

My first attempt is to adapt Groovy templates so I implemented the needed data types:

```
data GroovyWritable = mutable native groovy.lang.Writable where
  native writeTo :: GroovyWritable -> Writer -> IO Writer
      throws IOException

data GroovyTemplate = mutable native groovy.text.Template where
  native make :: GroovyTemplate -> HashMap -> IO GroovyWritable

data GroovyEngine = mutable native groovy.text.markup.MarkupTemplateEngine where
  native new            :: ()           -> IO GroovyEngine
  native createTemplate :: GroovyEngine -> BufferedReader -> IO GroovyTemplate
      throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
```

Then I did the correspondent instances:

```
instance Template GroovyTemplate where
   process template model = do -- model is not used at the moment
     config   <- HashMap.new ()
     writable <- GroovyTemplate.make template config
     stWriter <- StringWriter.new ()
     writer   <- writable.writeTo stWriter
     writer.toString

instance TemplateEngine GroovyEngine where
  buildTemplate engine reader = GroovyEngine.createTemplate engine reader
```

But the compiler is complaining with:

```
...
type `GroovyTemplate` is not as polymorphic as suggested
    in the annotation where just `α` is announced.
...
type error in expression createTemplate engine reader
    type is : IO GroovyTemplate
    expected: IO α
```

Any ideas ? Should I be using a different strategy ?
Thanks

**UPDATE**:

In order to explain what I'm trying to do I'm adding a function representing a generic way of building a template from a given template engine.

Lets say I haveI understand that Frege needs to be more precise about the types,  an instance of `TemplateEngine` and a `BufferedReader` containing the content of a template file, executing the `buildTemplate` function of a given engine should give me in return an instance of `Template`. This function here is compiling with no warnings at all.

```
execute :: (TemplateEngine a, Template b) => a -> BufferedReader -> IO b
execute engine reader = buildTemplate engine reader
```

I'm confused, why compiler is not complaining here ? Shouldn't it be complaining same way it did before ?

**UPDATE II (Working Solution)**:

Following Ingo's recommendation I went through the rationale behind my design and I've found a working solution.

In the beginning I thought it would be great to have`TemplateEngine` type class to create template engine instances the same way.

But the most important part was to have a common type class for dealing with templates, among other things, because templates can be cached. So the bottom line is that I don't care how templates are coming from as long as the resulting template is an instance of `Template`.

Following that premise then I can have a common function to process a template and get the resulting html/json/xml...etc.

```
execute :: (Template a) => a -> Model -> IO String
execute tpl model = tpl.process model
```

Of course the `production-ready` signature should be something like:

```
execute :: (Template a) => a -> Model -> Either TemplateException String
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are about to do, but as it stands, the `GroovyEngine.createTemplate` method cannot be used to instantiate teh `GroovyEngine` as `TemplateEngine`. Since the `buildTemplate` operation promises to return any `Template` the caller wants, provided that a `Template` instance is passed as argument.

Now, the first problem here is that native methods can't deal with type class constraints. We could work around this problem by wrapping the call to the native method with a frege function that actually uses the `Template` constraint. But then again, it is not clear how to actually create an appropriate value, since the `Template` class doesn't offer a corresponding operation. And the `GroovyEngine.createTemplate` still doen't qualify, because it always creates a specific template, not one that depends on the constraint.

Comment: * `Template` is not passed as argument but as a constraint. In fact is the return type.

Comment: a) `Template` in `createTemplate` is not an argument but a constraint. b) Could I define in the TemplateEngine class type the type parameter of the template ? That way I would be saying to Frege what is the concrete type of the Template right ?

Comment: One can think of type class constraints as implicit parameters. What gets passed here is the instance object itself, which is merely a record containing the functions that implement the type class.

Comment: I've added an update explaining a little bit more what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I'll edit my post later to scetch a possible solution involving a data type parameterized with a phantom type.

Comment: Thanks Ingo :) Looking forward to seeing it. In the meantime I came with a working solution for the specific problem based on your comments.